# Good Introductory HSPICE Books

Tags: books, spice

I have an assignment to create basic digital circuits in HSPICE using various manufacturing processes. I've written a couple of HSPICE decks, but it was just copying off a paper, and it was just gibberish to me. I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a good introductory book on Synopsys HSPICE? If the book you recommend was a textbook for a class, please indicate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I do not have any book for recommendation I have found that having general SPICE knowledge plus documentation provided with HSPICE is sufficient to work with it (I use hspice on daily basis).

The general spice knowledge you can get from many on line or paper tutorials. Any spice flavour will do (PSpice tutorials seems most common). It is important to stick to whatever is given in the text form and ignore anything on GUI. From the general "spice" knowledge tutorial you should get:

1. what is netlist and what are the rules of creating it
2. what are the analysis and what they do (.ac .dc .op .tran)
3. what are devices and device models (sources, passive devices - RLC, active devices M - cmos transistors, D - diodes)

The details are to get from HSPICE documentation.

The common gotchas to look out:

1. First line have to be always comment and is always treated as a comment
2. In order to get graphical results you have to tell spice explicitly to save the results (".option post" -> all voltage nodes OR ".probe" plus ".option post probe" to save only certain node voltages/currents)
3. To view graphical results you need separate program (avanwaves or cosmoscope or waveviewer)

The most useful hspice only features (at least for me) are:

1. .measure statements
2. .alters (used to run corner simulations)

Comment: You seem to know exactly what you're talking about. I did already learn about the first line needing to be a comment. Also, I have not been using a GUI. I've been working off a CentOS server with HSpice installed, and running the commands through terminal. I've been using cosmoscope to view the signals, because apparently ananwaves doesn't run on Linux. So are you saying you've never found use of any textbooks?

Comment: No I did no use any books (mainly because i did not have any). I was fortunate enough that I have learned spice at the university as a part of basic circuit analysis course. But all I get was rudimentary 0.5h introduction + 10 or so pages tutorial from the lecturer. We were using PSpice back then. When I started professional work it was enough to start using hspice without big problem. I have learned details and "quirks" of hspice from documentation and thru interactions with my colleagues from work.

Comment: @seljuq70 - My point is that if you will learn any spice it is easy to map its features to hspice (most of it will be exactly the same). So if you can get for example PSpice book that should be also great help.

Comment: I see... Well you've been extremely helpful. I looked up spice books on amazon. I found one that really caught my interest: "SPICE (Oxford Series in Electrical and Computer Engineering)". I was wondering if any general spice book will do, because there is nearly nothing for HSpice. I do plan on taking your advice about reading online tutorials though.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I think I might try out the book I previously mentioned, either way I have online tutorials to fall back on.